# Inconsistent Datetime format in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, datetime-format

I've some data for the month of August/2015 in dataframe in the following format:

```
Timestamp                  Value

2015-12-08 23:58:00          3.4 
2015-12-08 23:59:00          3.2
2015-08-13 00:00:00          1.1
2015-08-13 00:01:00          0.9
```

There are two formats available yy-dd-mm and yy-mm-dd (starting from 13 Aug). I am struggling to convert these to a common format. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is a difficult question and requires fuzzy logic and far more data that you've provided.  Using what you have, I can determine that I should convert `'2015-12-08'` to `'2015-08-12'` but that is only in the context of what's next to it.  Point is, this isn't a pandas question.  Rather, it's a who do you yell at for messing up the data question.

Comment: I've full month data starting from Aug/01 to Aug/31. The problem is that the dateformat of the data from Aug/01 to Aug/12 is in yy-dd-mm and from Aug/13 to Aug/31 is in yy-mm-dd. I just need a consistent datetime format without changing the values column.

Comment: How do you know its August data? And not December data? Answer to this question can provide logic in cleanup process.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the strings to datatime, starting in the expected correct format, and ask to ignore errors:

```
df['Correct'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp,
                               format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',
                               errors='coerce')


df.Correct
Out[34]: 
0   2015-08-12 23:58:00
1   2015-08-12 23:59:00
2                   NaT
3                   NaT
Name: Correct, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now you know where to apply the second format:

```
df.Correct.update(pd.to_datetime(df[df.Correct.isnull()].Timestamp,
                                 format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                                 errors='coerce'))
df
Out[36]: 
             Timestamp  Val             Correct
0  2015-12-08 23:58:00  3.4 2015-08-12 23:58:00
1  2015-12-08 23:59:00  3.2 2015-08-12 23:59:00
2  2015-08-13 00:00:00  1.1 2015-08-13 00:00:00
3  2015-08-13 00:01:00  0.9 2015-08-13 00:01:00
```